# terminal folder access

Tags: macos, terminal

having a trouble to access few folders in my root user. For example: cannot access - `Ideas Infinitas`, `Treehouse workshops` folders. At the same time I can access `test_app` and some other folders.

[image: logged in as a root user]

My root user is the user I'm logged in with, find image below.

How do I have an access to these folders?

[image: directory utility]

Comment: Being logged in as **root** using a Terminal while not knowing how to use it is a dangerous combination!

Comment: so you were born knowing all the answers to the life's questions, so it seems :) congrats

Comment: No, nor did I say anything of the sort and what I previous said was only meant  to be cautionary in nature.  The **root** account in OS X is disabled by default for very good reasons.

Comment: Well, apologies to you sir/madame. It was out of order from my saide to assert the situation the way I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder name contains a space which means that the shell interprets it as two separate arguments. Either escape the space with a `\` or enclose the string in `"`.

```
cd "folder name"
cd folder\ name
```